# How to run the scripts from outside the folder structure having the code in Rails 2.3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to run the oldest Rails project which is developed in 2.3.2 version. The folder structure looks some what different like this:

```
my_project 
   |-> scripts -> ex.rb
               -> data.rb
   |-> MyMonitor -> app
                -> config
                -> db...
```

The folder under MyMonitor is having Rails folder structure, I am able to run the application but I need to run the scripts under *my_project -> scripts* folder.

Please help me what is the command or how to run the scripts?

I tried the following:

```
user@sachin:-~/Desktop/my_projects/MyMonitor$ load './my_project/scripts/ex.rb'
```

but didn't helped me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referencing your file path incorrectly. Try this:

```
load '../scripts/ex.rb'
```

Or, if it is not working, you can always use absolute path (but with obvious disadvantages).

```
# If you are on OSX and your username is 'user'
load '/Users/user/Desktop/my_projects/scripts/ex.rb'
```

**Update:** Author wants to run the file from command line.

```
ruby '../scripts/ex.rb'
```

Comment: When I run the above command I am getting:       ` No command 'load' found, did you mean:
 Command 'xload' from package 'x11-apps' (main)
 Command 'nload' from package 'nload' (universe)
 Command 'tload' from package 'procps' (main)
load: command not found'`

Comment: I see... you need to run that command within you ruby environment (e.g. `irb`). Do you want to run from command line? Then simply use `ruby '../scripts/ex.rb'`.